# Pentaho Data Integration: The job keeps running even though it has succeeded

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a simple job of moving data from source to destination with some transformations. Most of the times the job succeeds without any issues. But lately when I run the job, it kind of gets stuck in the last with the hourglass symbol stating that the job is still in progress, whereas it has actually completed and data is present in the destination. Then I myself have to stop the job. And when I do so, the last job shows the green tick mark.

I want the job to successfully run without any intervention.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the GUI doesn't refresh properly. Check the logging for the job finished entry and/or click on any white area on the canvas, it should update to the correct status after a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't see "success" step in your screenshot. If you have missed that please add success step at end. Otherwise it wont be stopped.

Comment: I have added the success step but still somehow it gets stuck in the previous step (Job 3 in this case)

Comment: Do you have success step in all job 1 to 3?

Comment: the job succeeds in 1 and 2 but the hourglass icon remains constant in job 3. However, when I stop the job and check the destination table, the record has been entered successfully.

Comment: I’m asking do you have success step in job 3 also? If not add and check

Comment: I added the success step after Job 3 but the it still gets stuck at job 3 and does not go till the Success step

Comment: @Kuldip.Das you have added success step in main job that’s correct, check you have added success step in job 3 also. If not then add and check

Comment: Yes, the workflow is succeeding now. Apart from adding Success step within the Job 3 workflow, there was another issue which was causing the job to fail. I checked the options - Enable cache? ; Load all data from table - and the job succeeded and therefore the main job succeeded as well.

Comment: Job should also finish succesfull without the succes step. It is not as nicely created, and most likely against your local guidelines, and not advisable, but it still should be fine without it

Answer (score 0):

check the "start" at job 3, maybe the repeat box is checked. Uncheck the repeat box, hope this help :)